# Change color when radio button is changed

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, checked

JQuery:

```
$(function() 
{
    $(':radio[name="noir"]').click(function()
    {
        $('#h1color')
            .addClass('noir')
            .removeClass('vert')
            .removeClass('rouge')
            .html('Je suis noir !');
    });
    $(':radio[name="vert"]').click(function()
    {
        $('#h1color')
            .addClass('vert')
            .removeClass('noir')
            .removeClass('rouge')
            .html('Je suis vert !');
    });

    $(':radio[name="rouge"]').click(function()
    {
        $('#h1color')
            .addClass('rouge')
            .removeClass('vert')
            .removeClass('noir')
            .html('Je suis rouge !');
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="post">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="noir"/>Noir <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="vert"/>Vert<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="rouge"/>Rouge<br/>
</form>
<h1 id="h1color">Je suis Noir !</h1>
```

But when I check a radio, the text doesn't change color and string.

Where is my error ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(function() {

    $(':radio[value="noir"]').click(function(){
        $('#h1color').addClass('noir').removeClass('vert').removeClass('rouge').html('Je suis noir !');
    });
    $(':radio[value="vert"]').click(function(){
        $('#h1color').addClass('vert').removeClass('noir').removeClass('rouge').html('Je suis vert !');
    });
    $(':radio[value="rouge"]').click(function(){
        $('#h1color').addClass('rouge').removeClass('vert').removeClass('noir').html('Je suis rouge !');
    }); 
});
```

You were checking for name attribute which was same. You have to check for value

Comment: Thank you, it's just this... ^^

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten that to

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="color"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#h1color').removeClass().addClass(this.value).html('Je suis '+this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hshbc/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").on("click", "input", function(e) {
        var $header = $("#h1color");
        if (e.target.type == "radio") {
            var $colour = $(this).val();
            $header.removeClass().addClass($colour).text("Je suis " + $colour);
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X3PnV/)